# core data to-many relationship set count doesn't update until app restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm pretty stumped with this one, but most likely I am misunderstanding something about Core Data again.

I have 2 managed objects: `Bag` and `Item`.  They both have 'to-many' direct and reverse relationships.

So I am adding an `Item` to `Bag` by calling the `addItemsObject:` from my `Bag` class.

Now I want to see how many `Bag` objects have that `Item`, so I am doing:

```
// in my Bag implementation:
- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)inKey withSetMutation:(NSKeyValueSetMutationKind)inMutationKind usingObjects:(NSSet *)inObjects
{
    Item *myItem = [inObjects anyObject]; // for simplicity, but this is returning my added Item for sure.
    NSInteger count = myItem.bags.count;
    NSLog(@"%@ is in %li bags", myItem.name, (long)count);  
    // keeps on giving me "0 bag"
}
```

Can anybody tell me what's going on?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not (and should not) implement the KVC accessor `- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)inKey withSetMutation:(NSKeyValueSetMutationKind)inMutationKind usingObjects:(NSSet *)inObjects`. The Core Data generated accessors will implement that for you.

Overriding this method is likely part of your problem. You will note that the [documentation for this method says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-SW29):

> You must not override this method.

You can use other mechanisms, such as KVO, to be notified of changes to this property.

Comment: overriding that method is strongly discouraged, but it isn't so bad.. you actually just have to update the to-many set properties manually, but i'll still mark ur answer as correct ~thanks!

Comment: No, it is. You should *NOT* override that method. The relationship faulting behaviors of Core Data depend on it working in a specific way - which is why when overriding it, that was breaking for you.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Thanks.